# Why isn't this more concise restatement of the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem more commonly used?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why isn't the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem simply stated as follows?

> The image $f(U)$ of an analytic function $f : U \subset \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ with an essential singularity is a dense subset of the complex plane.

Note that

1. The statement implicitly states that $U$ is a punctured neighborhood of the essential singularity.
2. If $U' \subset U$ is a sub-[punctured neighborhood] of the essential singularity, then the restriction $f \mid U'$ is again an analytic function with an essential singularity at the same place, hence $f(U')$ is again a dense subset of the complex plane.

What is gained by explicitly mentioning punctured neighborhoods in the theorem statement?

Comment: Surely something should be said about the set $U$ in the complex plane?

Comment: @hardmath: Ah, yes, sorry.

Comment: Some people also call branch points and other non-isolated singularities essential, so to be on the safe side, you could talk about "isolated essential singularities". // What is gained by mentioning punctured neighbourhoods? Explicitness. One doesn't need the reader to do work and wonder whether we actually know what we're saying if we're explicit.

Comment: You ask what is gained... Perhaps clarity of expression? Even your own question becomes clearer with the "Note that..."